# Inno Setup Delete method not working as expected

Tags: inno-setup

I have an application version that includes a hash. For sake of the installer, I want a simple version without the hash. I have the following code which mostly works, the part in question is the `Delete` call which according to the [documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=delete) `Deletes the specified number of characters beginning with Index from S. S is passed by reference (therefore is modified).`

```
#define FullAppVersion "0.0.9 - abcdef012345"
#expr WriteIni("D:\\debug.txt", "Debug", "Full", FullAppVersion)

#define SimpleVersion FullAppVersion
#expr WriteIni("D:\\debug.txt", "Debug", "SimpleBefore", SimpleVersion)

#define HashPos Pos(' ', SimpleVersion)
#expr WriteIni("D:\\debug.txt", "Debug", "Pos", HashPos)

#expr Delete(SimpleVersion, HashPos)
#expr WriteIni("D:\\debug.txt", "Debug", "SimpleAfter", SimpleVersion)
```

However, when the above is executed, the debug looks as such:

```
[Debug]
Full=0.0.9 - abcdef012345
SimpleBefore=0.0.9 - abcdef012345
Pos=6
SimpleAfter=0.0.90.0.9 - abcdef012345
```

`Delete` seems to partially work by trimming from the specified position, but then additionally concatenates the entire string at the end.

Am I doing something incorrectly, or is there a glitch in the function? Using Inno Setup Compiler 5.5.5 and Inno Script Studio 2.2.1.31

Comment: That is a bug. For now you can use `Copy`, or specify the number of chars to delete.

Comment: Good to know. `Copy` is probably a better way to do it anyway. Thanks